# How to get bytecode from revisions of git

Tags: git, repository, bytecode, revision

I am working on a research project. I need to run findbugs over transactions of git repository. I need to get bytecode (compiled version) of each revision.

I wonder whether or not there is an infrastructure helps me for example by getting revisions from git repository and compile them. Or in case i should do it myself what should i do?

Would you please help me with referring to a tool or instructions?

I look forward to hearing from you.

Best regards,
Zahra

Comment: Bytecode for… Java? C#? Something else? You need to specify language & tools.

Comment: I think what's really being asked here is "how can I iterate over all Git revisions, and compile/whatever the code at that revision?".

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that there are existing tools to help with this, but you could do this fairly simply with something like the following (assuming *nix):

```
for rev in $(git rev-list master); do
    git checkout $rev
    # Compilation steps here
done
```

Comment: Woowww Many thanks and can i use this simple insurrections automatically in Java

Comment: Or Is it possible to save these revisions